# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'permalink'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, machine-learning, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error. How can I solve it?

```
**@models.permalink
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'permalink'**
```

Comment: Share the full traceback together with the model where you used that decorator. What Django version do you use?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 9):

As of [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11), the [`@permalink` decorator was marked deprecated <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.11/#models-permalink-decorator), and since [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), the [`@permalink` decorator is removed <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1). There has been [some discussion regarding this decorator](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18974), and eventually the Django developers decided to remove it.

Instead of using the `@permalink` decorator for the [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), one is now responsible to return the correct values.

This thus means that if you have a model that uses the decorator, you change this from:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('name-of-some-view', 'extra', 'parameters')
```

you have to use the [**`reverse(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.urls import reverse

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name-of-some-view', args=('extra', 'parameters'))
```